# mozilla / safari address bar css problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a css problem on my post pages under 800px i have a button sticky on the bottom of the page, but it interacts badly with the mozilla/safari bottom bar…

```
<button class="ocs-trigger ocs-toggle ocs-toggle-posts-toc-mobile">Περιεχόμενα</button>
```

More specifically on mozilla if the mozilla bottom address bar is hidden, the button isnt clickable.
And on safari the button is clickable but the off canvas panel that it opens is appearing with space under it when the safari address bar is hidden…
Instead of being on the bottom of the page…

I think you maybe know about similar problems with safari mozilla bottom bar and you can give me a direction to start researching about this problem?

I thank you in advance for any pointers given.
https://thefinterest.kinsta.cloud/p/asjalska/

Comment: You can try using JS to check the browser and move the buttons accordingly. Here is a link how to find the browser using vanilla JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Comment: thank you for the info, but the problem resides more specifically in the address bar being hidden... When the address bar on the bottom is visible everything works ok, when it hides i get the unwanted "look"..